# GetSchema() throws UciException "*HS.OLEDBINFO" is not in the CATALOG space"

Tags: u2, universe, unidata, uniobjects

I installed UniVerse on the administrator account of a Parallels Windows installation.  I subsequently created a second administrator account whose credentials I'm using to create the U2Connection.

However, when attempting to call GetSchema(...) I'm getting the following exception.  I suspect this is permission-related but I'm not sure what I need to change.

{" [U2][UCINET-UO] [U2][UCINET][UNIVERSE]:\"*HS.OLEDBINFO\" is not in the CATALOG space.\r\n"}

at U2.Data.Client.Ucinet.UciStatement.ExecuteDirect(String pSQL)
   at U2.Data.Client.U2Command.a(CommandBehavior A_0)
   at U2.Data.Client.U2Command.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, U2CursorType reqCursorType, Boolean abortOnOptValueChg, Boolean skipDeleted, Boolean isResultSet, Int32 maxRows, Boolean skipInitialValidation)
   at U2.Data.Client.U2Command.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at U2.Data.Client.U2MetaDataFactory.b(U2Command& A_0, String A_1)
   at U2.Data.Client.U2MetaDataFactory.v(String[] A_0)
   at U2.Data.Client.U2MetaDataFactory.GetSchema(String collectionName, String[] restrictionValues)
   at U2.Data.Client.U2Connection.GetSchema(String collectionName, String[] restrictionValues)
   at U2.Data.Client.U2Connection.GetSchema(String collectionName)
   at Connection.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Rocket Software\U2 Toolkit for .NET\U2 Database Provider\samples\C#\UniVerse\Connection\Program.cs:line 30

Answer (score 0):

I'm told: He is right for the second administrator account. All UniVerse users must have the permission to access the global catalog subroutines. That “*HS.OLEDBINFO” (%AHS.OLEDBINFO) will be in the “C:\U2\UV\catdir” folder by default.

Does that help?

Comment: If I recall, ultimately the issue was due to a bad install of UniVerse.